# What mechanism is used to determine the absolute order of vertices in tinkerpop/titan?

Tags: titan, tinkerpop

When performing the following traversals:

```
graph.addVertex("a")
graph.addVertex("b")
graph.addVertex("c")

graph.traversal().V().range(0,2)
graph.traversal().V().range(2,3)
```

What determines the order in which I get these vertices back when using the range functionality? Am I guaranteed to get all three vertices a, b and c back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without an explicit `order().by()` you shouldn't expect a guaranteed order.

From the TinkerPop docs:

> A Traversal’s result are never ordered unless explicitly by means of
>   `order()`-step. Thus, never rely on the iteration order between
>   TinkerPop3 releases and even within a release (as traversal
>   optimizations may alter the flow).

Comment: My unit tests show that this is working at the moment. Does it use something like the vertex id by default or is it just "luck"?

Comment: It's just luck and nobody can guarantee that you'll still see the same default order in TinkerPop's next release.